# Shared appsettings.json file between web and console VS project at .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm setting a appsettings.json file for shared between any projects .net Core (Web, Console and Library).
I setup a shared file follow the step of this post https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/ , but i can't read file in console project.

this is the code that i have tried

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("SharedSettings.json", optional: true, 
            reloadOnChange: true);

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

        Console.WriteLine("Connection string: " + configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

this is my project structure

[image]

in my project web the code for read file it is, i need read shared .json in the other's project.

```
  public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => {
      IHostingEnvironment env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

  // find the shared folder in the parent folder
  var sharedFolder = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "..", "Shared");

  //load the SharedSettings first, so that appsettings.json overrwrites it
  config
   .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(sharedFolder, "SharedSettings.json"), optional: true) // When running using dotnet run
   .AddJsonFile("SharedSettings.json", optional: true) // When app is published
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
   .AddJsonFile($ "appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

  config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
 })
 .UseStartup < Startup > ()
 .Build();
```

Comment: Can you provide the full path between these two solutions?

Comment: have you marked it as copy to the output directory?

Comment: Do you want it to simply work in Visual Studio or to eventually Build to prep for deployment?

Comment: I want it work in development and production, my problem is that not can't read the file in other projects only in web

Comment: Are they all separate applications or do they have a dependency to your web application?

Comment: some have dependecy, not all have reference to the web project

Comment: @JhonDiaz Then all of those projects would need a `IConfigurationBuilder` to be constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Without your `ConfigurationBuilder` implementation and how you are passing `IConfiguration` to your dependencies.  Are they stand alone applications for instance?

For the other application, you can achieve your desired result by doing the following:

1. On appsettings.json file in solution, open properties.
2. Build to output directory.

When you are inside Visual Studio the application should read your appsettings.json without an issue.  For my solution I created a directory called Configuration with two sub-directories Development and Production.  Now when Visual Studio builds it should adhere to the above configuration mentioned, but to create a separate Build directory that is not apart of your bin I utilized a PowerShell script.

```
Param($configuration="Development")

if($configuration.ToUpper().StartsWith("P")) {
     $configuration="Production"
} else {
     $configuration="Development"
}

if((Test-Path .\Build)) {
     Remove-Item -r -fo .\Build
}

New-Item -ItemType Directory .\Build | Out-Null
dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime win81-x64 --verbosity Quiet --self-contained true
Copy-Item -r .\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\win81-x64\publish\* .\Build\

Remove-Item .\Build\*.pdb
Remove-Item .\Build\appsettings.json

Copy-Item .\Configuration\$configuration\appsettings.json .\Build\
Copy-Item ".\Configuration\Deployment Resources\Script\*.ps1" .\Build\
Copy-Item ".\Configuration\Deployment Resources\Task\*.xml" .\Build\

echo "`n`n"
Write-Host "╭ ─────────────────────────── ╮"
Write-Host "         $configuration              "
Write-Host "╰ ─────────────────────────── ╯"
echo "`n`n"
```

To build, I navigate to my solution on command line and simply do: `.\Build.ps1 Production` or `.\Build.ps1` and it will create a valid Build directory for me.  You can ignore some of the other components, since they're for a scheduled task, install scripts, etc. that we also include so when we use a deploy script everything transfers to remote server.

I will modify answer once you provide more information about how your other projects are linked to your web solution.